# Do cancellations of in-app subscription trials appear on App Store Connect (formerly iTunes Connect)?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, subscriptions, itunesconnect-analytics

I have an app that has a 1-month trial of an in-app auto-renewing subscription. This past week I've been able to get over 300 trial sign ups. What I'm NOT seeing is any cancellations during the trial period, and I find that hard to believe.

Does App Store Connect show cancellations that happen **during a trial period** or not, because right now I am showing **ZERO** cancellations? Am I just really fortunate with my numbers here? Or am I flying blind and the numbers aren't telling me the full story yet?

In App Store Connect, under Sales and Trends > Subscriptions > Summary, I am showing the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Users don't cancel free trials as such.  They just cancel the automatic renewal, so you won't see a renewal event at the end of free trial period.

Comment: You're correct, you can't "cancel a trial", but I would like to know when auto-renew gets turned off during a trial period. It's a useful stat so I know if I'm likely to get ROI on ad spend or not. Out of my almost 400 trials this week, they could all be cancelled, or none, so who knows? It's a black box. I'm shocked Apple doesn't give big first-party devs this info.

Comment: As far as I know, App Store Connect doesn't ever report on cancelled subscriptions.  Only renewals.  You have to compute the number of cancellations based on "last month active + new subscriptions - this month active".  Over time you can also use subscription retention reports.

Comment: @Paulw11 Per [this page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/#measuring-subscriptions-with-sales-and-trends), viewing cancellations does seem to be possible: "_You can also see the number of cancellations as well as certain reasons for cancellation._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found cancellation ("churn") metrics in App Store Connect.

Go to the **Trends** module, then in the sidebar under "Subscriptions" click on **Summary** and **Retention** — each of those pages has some metrics related to cancellation. In some places they split out conversion rates from trials, promotions, and renewals.